# Why isn't the member variable passed to a function modified?

Tags: c++, class

I'm still exploring C++ trying to figure out how it works and came across something that puzzles me.

I have a class that simply holds a `list<string>` and has a few member functions

```
class String_list {
      public:
            String_list(istream&);
            //other functions
            list<string> listing;
};
```

and I wrote my constructor to use a non-member function

```
String_list::String_list(istream& in) { get_strings(in, listing); }
```

with

```
istream& get_strings(istream& in, list<string> lstring)
{
  if(in) {
       lstring.clear();

       string word;

       while (in >> word) 
               lstring.push_back(word);

       in.clear();
       }
  return in;
 }
```

The problem is, though the `get_string` function seems to work, it doesn't change the `listing` member variable I passed to it.

I can get it to work by making `get_strings` a member function with one argument `(istream& in)` by just changing `lstring` to `listing`, so I assume that either the passing of the list from the constructor doesn't work for some reason, or that the non-member function can't change the member-variable, but these seems like the sort of things my compiler would easily pick up on.

My compiler doesn't see any problem with the code it's just when I run the executable that the member list always has `.size()` of 0.

Comment: Duplicate of over 9,000 questions. Which C++ book are you using?

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel Apologies - I assumed it was specifically something to do with classes and searched in the wrong place.

Comment: Next time I'm sure you'll narrow down the problem further by checking with a basic function :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're passing a copy of your member variable to the function.  The local copy is modified, while the member variable is not.

Change the signature of your `get_strings` function to take a reference to your list object and this will work:

```
istream& get_strings(istream& in, list<string>& lstring)
{
   // ...
}
```

Though this breaks encapsulation, in your case (exposing directly the member variable to that function).  A better method may be to have the `get_strings` function return a copy of the list it populates, then assign it to your class's member in an initializer list.  Like this:

```
list<string> get_strings(istream& in)
{
   list<string> r;
   // ...
   return r;
}
```

Then your constructor:

```
StringList::StringList(istream& in) : listing(get_strings(in))
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: To clarify for the OP you need to use list<string>& lstring where '&' is the identifier to say 'reference-to'

Comment: @user876651: `&` is not an identifier. An identifier is an arbitrarily long sequence of letters and digits (`[C++11: 2.11/1]`).

Comment: My bad, this is called the reference modifier.

Answer (score 10):

You should pass `lstring` by reference:

```
istream& get_strings(istream& in, list<string>& lstring)
```

The code compiles and works as it is written : passing the *value* of lstring, thus copying it. All the changes are made on a temporary object, then discarded when the object is destroyed.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ you're passing by value, not by reference unless you do it explicitly. So if you declare your function:

```
istream& get_strings(istream& in, list<string> lstring)
```

then `lstring` is passed by value, which means that you're not using the same object you're passing in a function call. You simply make a copy of this object and even though you modify it in a function body, you only modify this copy.

If you want to modify an object which you pass, you should pass it by reference, which you can achieve by using `&`:

```
istream& get_strings(istream& in, list<string>& lstring)
```